# Propagating recursive property if all predecessors satisfy it

Tags: datalog

I am working on a directed acyclic graph where a node can satisfy a property. I want to propagate this property recursively on other nodes. The rule is that a node satisfies this property if and only if all of its direct predecessors satisfy it as well.

The following of course does not work, since it would be enough if ONE parent satisfied the property, while I need ALL parents to satisfy it in order to propagate.

```
satisfies(node) :- isParent(parent, node), satisfies(parent).
```

Things I tried:

- writing a `doesNotSatisfy` rule instead, which would work, but by doing that, I ran into the exact same issue elsewhere in the program
- negating the thing with a `!`, but that gave me cyclic negations

What helped me in the past with datalog was to solve the problem naturally as a human on paper. But here I don't see any other way than to try to satisfy the "for all" rule.

Is that somehow possible in datalog? And if yes, how?

Comment: Could you point how what is wrong with notSatisfy predicate?

    notSatisfies(Node) :- isParent(Parent, Node), notSatisfies(Parent).
    satisfies(Node) :- isParent(Parent, Node), not notSatisfies(Parent).

Comment: So the only way to "for all" predicate is the negated version? That is what I was scared of. This is just a minimal example of what does not work, later there appears a predicate that causes cyclic negation with `notSatisfies`. So apparently none of these are what I want and I probably have a design error somewhere. Might it be possible that a correct design does not exist?

Comment: A general alternative is to use an extension of "standard" Datalog or to consider particular syntactic restrictions. And yes: Maybe it is impossible to describe your design in "standard" datalog. There are more expressive formalisms, like vadalog, stable models, ...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, what you describe can certainly be achieved with standard Datalog without introducing cyclical negative dependencies. You need two things

1. `forall p = ! exists ! p`, which it seems you already figured out
2. seperation of base property and derived property

Here's a very generic example that you can easily adapt.

Here's a simple graph: the nodes with `+` possess the basic property (base case). The ones with * are those for which all successors satisfy the property.

```
1 -- 2 -- 3 * --- 5 + *
     |\    \----- 6 + *
     | \-- 4 * -- 8 + *
     \---- 7
```

First, encode the graph.

```
transition(1,2).
transition(2,3).
transition(2,4).
transition(3,5).
transition(3,6).
transition(2,7).
transition(4,8).
```

Auxiliary to enumerate all nodes.

```
node(Node) :- transition(Node, _).
node(Node) :- transition(_, Node).
```

Mark the base case (`+` nodes).

```
property(5).
property(6).
property(8).
```

Find nodes that does not have to property.

```
notProperty(Node) :- node(Node), ! property(Node).
```

Now we figure out the `*` nodes. Either we know it trivially via `property(Node)`. Or that we can transition to a node where it is not the case that property does not hold.

```
propertyDerived(Node) :- property(Node).
propertyDerived(Node) :- transition(Node,Next), ! notProperty(Next).
```

The reason the program can avoid cyclical negation is because I have separated `propertyDerived` from `property` which in your example is confounded.

Now if you query, you'd get what you expect!

```
?- propertyDerived(Node).
 3
 4
 5
 6
 8
```